# Facebook Graph api Search post with Picture

Tags: json, facebook, api, get

So If I post a status update on Facebook with a photo (public), I want to use Graph Search api to find it.

Here is the link I've been using:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23tacomaevent&type=post

I am hoping to be able to use the hashtag such as #tacomaevent so I can search for public text and picture post.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would be also interested in finding a solution !

Comment: I tried the same but looks like the search results is ignoring all posts with pictures, anyone has a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and would like to point out that, as of now, the search you proposed returns a JSON string containing a list of Facebook **Post** objects, which may have a property named **picture**. This property will contain an URL of the picture if one is available.

It has many other properties and they're [documented here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post).